# Problema com gráfico em Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Através de cálculos e expressões matemáticas, partindo da informação de três dados informados pelo usuário (Distância do lançamento - 
Tempo de duração - Altura máxima atingida), calcular as velocidades que estão envolvidas (Velocidade em X - Velocidade em Y).

Até aí tudo ok!

A questão é, como "*simular*" um gráfico com estes cálculos ?

**Exemplo:**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parábola que ilustra a posição vertical (Altura - que no código entende-se por "num3") em função do tempo (Tempo - que no código entende-se por "num2")
utilizando os seguintes pontos:

- Ponto 1: Parte do zero;
- Ponto 2: Sobe até o ponto: x = metade do tempo informada pelo usuário e
  y = altura máxima informada;
- Ponto 3: Desce do ponto anterior até o ponto: x = tempo total
  informado pelo usuário e y = Zero;

**Já tentei o seguinte:**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num1 = int(input("Digite a distância percorrida - em metros: "))
num2 = int(input("Digite o tempo de duração do lançamento - em segundos: "))
num3 = int(input("Digite a altura máxima atingida no lançamento - em metros: "))
print()
distancia = num1
tempo = num2
altura = num3
velocidadex = num1/num2
veloy1 = num2*num2
veloy2 = veloy1*4.9
veloy3 = num3+veloy2
veloy4 = veloy3/num2
velocidadey = veloy4
print("A velocidade em X é: ", velocidadex)
print("LEMBRETE: A unidade de velocidade é 'm/s'")
print()
print("A velocidade em y é: ", velocidadey)
print("LEMBRETE: A unidade de velocidade é 'm/s'")
print("O calculo utiliza 4.9 como sendo o termo de 1/2 da gravidade")
print()
print("A distância informada foi: ", distancia)
print("LEMBRETE: A unidade da distância é 'm'")
print()
print("O tempo informado foi: ", tempo)
print("LEMBRETE: A unidade do tempo é '/s'")
print()
print("A altura máxima informada foi: ", altura)
print("LEMBRETE: A unidade da altura é 'm'")
print()
l=input()

x=[]
y=[]
half = distancia / 2;
a = 0
b = 0;

bHlp = altura / distancia

x.append(a)
y.append(b)

while True:
    if a < half:
        a=a+0.5
        #x.append(a)

    if b < altura:
        b=b+bHlp
        #y.append(b)

    if a >= half and b >= altura:
        break

    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)

b = altura;
while True:
    if a < distancia:
        a=a+0.5
        #x.append(a)

    if b <= altura:
        b=b-bHlp
        #y.append(b)

    if a >= distancia and b <= 0:
        break

    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)

plt.title('Exemplo de Gráfico')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Eixo x')
plt.ylabel('Eixo y')
plt.plot(x,y,"v","r")
plt.show()

plt.savefig("chart");
```

**Tenho como saída:**

```
#A velocidade em X é:  12.833333333333334
#LEMBRETE: A unidade de velocidade é 'm/s'
#
#A velocidade em y é:  31.066666666666666
#LEMBRETE: A unidade de velocidade é 'm/s'
#O calculo utiliza 4.9 como sendo o termo de 1/2 da gravidade
#
#A distância informada foi:  77
#LEMBRETE: A unidade da distância é 'm'
#
#O tempo informado foi:  6
#LEMBRETE: A unidade do tempo é '/s'
#
#A altura máxima informada foi:  10
#LEMBRETE: A unidade da altura é 'm'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem notar, o gráfico não fica exatamente uma "parábola" e é exatamente este o meu problema, não consigo pensar em algo para melhorar a lógica e consequentemente o gráfico.

Comment: Isso porque uma parábola é definida por uma equação de segundo grau, mas não consegui identificar no seu código tal equação.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss concordo com você. Não é necessariamente uma parábola que devo fazer mas somente "simular" o exemplo que mostrei.

Comment: @8biT, não consigo vislumbar como simular uma parabola sem uma equação que define uma parabola. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou tentar responder baseando-me na imagem do exemplo mas sem "fazer a lição de casa", a primeira coisa que voce precisa fazer é descobrir a equação da parabola, perceba que na figura do exemplo já são apresentadas informações que podem te levar à descoberta da equação, o vértice da mesma, por exemplo, o google é seu amigo.

Digamos que pesquise e encontre a equação: `(10*(x-38.5)**2+5)*-1`, alerta: Essa não é a equação da parábola da figura que vc apresentou na pergunta, é apenas um exemplo. Considerando isso, teriamos o codigo:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0,77,9)
y =  (10*(x-38.5)**2+5)*-1
plt.plot(x,y);
plt.title("Exemplo de parábola")
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

O que resultaria no gráfico:

[image: Gráfico resultante]

> Editada

Minha sugestão até aqui vale para a descoberta da equação baseada em uma informação apresentada na figura, analisando seu codigo vi que, na verdade, é ainda mais simples, procure pela dedução da equação do movimento obliquo, ou lançamento obliquo.

Comment: Deu certo! Confesso que achei complicado a lógica para implementar o lançamento. Encontrei alguns exemplos e apliquei juntamente com o seu e parece tudo certo! Grato.